# How can I share a variable from a thread to my main in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm trying to share two variables for a comparation in a conditional in my main, but I am getting errors whenever I set the variables as global, saying that the variable was started before global statement.

Here is a peek to the code:

```
#thread timer for minute
class myMin(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global now
        global timestart
        n=1 
        while True:
            n=1
            timestart = time.time()
            now = time.time()
            while now-timestart <= 10:
                now = time.time()
            print('banana')
            n=0
#thread timer for the hour
class myHour(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global now2
        global timestart2
        m=1
        while True:
            m=1
            timestart2=time.time()
            now2 = time.time()
            while now2-timestart2 <= 20:
                now2 = time.time()
            print('uvas')
            m =0 

mymin=myMin()
myhour=myHour()

#thread execution
mymin.start()  

myhour.start() 

#Main program counting
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    global m
    global n 
    count = count+1
    countperhour=countperhour+1
    countpermin=countpermin+1
    if m == 0:
        copm = countpermin
        countpermin=0
    if n == 0:
        coph=countperhour
        countpermin=0
```

Comment: you need to declare them BEFORE applying global to them. so in your main context (before the classes) do something like `now = now2 = timestart = timestart2 = n = m = None`. it's ugly but it will work. a better solution is to understand what you are trying to do and design for it. also, remember that threads can talk to each others data without issue (one of the benefits of the GIL)

Comment: I understand, yet they do not change for the "ifs" to start working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be declaring global m, n inside your loop.
There are other improvements that can be done to your code but below one runs

```
from threading import Thread
import time
#thread timer for minute
class myMin(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global now
        global timestart
        n=1
        while True:
            n=1
            timestart = time.time()
            now = time.time()
            while now-timestart <= 10:
                now = time.time()
            print('banana')
            n=0
#thread timer for the hour
class myHour(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global now2
        global timestart2
        m=1
        while True:
            m=1
            timestart2=time.time()
            now2 = time.time()
            while now2-timestart2 <= 20:
                now2 = time.time()
            print('uvas')
            m =0


count = 0
countperhour = 0
countpermin = 0

global m
global n
m, n = 0,0
mymin=myMin()
myhour=myHour()

#thread execution
mymin.start()

myhour.start()

#Main program counting
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    count = count+1
    countperhour=countperhour+1
    countpermin=countpermin+1
    if m == 0:
        copm = countpermin
        countpermin=0
    if n == 0:
        coph=countperhour
        countpermin=0
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. The thing is, when I run the code in that way the conditional in my main do not change, as in m and n do not change between 1 and 0 for the other variables to reset,

Comment: @AstridDunning you didnt make `m`, `n`  `global` inside your threads, so they dont affect your outer `m` and `n`

Comment: I just did as you suggested and erased the global variables from it and added on the threeads, there was a sincronization error, with some time.sleep() I got it working. Thank you so much!